# Unable to start activity because of NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

My code works whenever I do not have the "Startup" activity as the first one.  It works when my Main Activity is the first one and goes through the entire app with all working functions.  I must have something missing to make this page the one that works at the start of an application.

LogCat

```
10-30 20:30:22.137: D/AndroidRuntime(783): Shutting down VM
10-30 20:30:22.137: W/dalvikvm(783): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidassignment2/com.example.androidassignment2.Startup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.example.androidassignment2.Startup.onCreate(Startup.java:19)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-30 20:30:22.147: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  ... 11 more
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/Hello"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:text="@string/Hello" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/QuitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_quit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code

```
package com.example.androidassignment2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Startup extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startup);


        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QButton);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

AND lastly the manifest.xml file.  Where is suspect a problem could be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.androidassignment2"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.Startup"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1" >

    </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_4"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_5"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.Goodbye"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_assignment2_1">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The important part is: NullPointerException.

Comment: This question should be closed as it's too localized.  It's unlikely to help any future visitors.

Comment: @blahdiblah I don't agree. It's a well prepared question and a common mistake in Android development when you mistype an id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button id is wrong. `QButton` is not defined in your xml.

Instead of

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QButton);
```

use

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QuitButton);
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something tiny.